# Add two constraints to a protocol var

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following swit code, and I can't manage to make it compile

```
public protocol A {}
public protocol A2 {}

public protocol B {
    var props: A { get }
}

public protocol C : B {
    var props: A2 { get }
}


struct D :  A,A2 {
}


struct Yo : C {
    var props: D
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add two type constraints to the var "props" both: `A` as part of the protocol `B` and `A2` as part of the protocol `C`.

When I try to implement those protocols in the struct `C` the compiler doesn't see that as valid

Comment: `A` and `A2` are not related. `C` is a `B` (inheritance), if `C.props` returns a different type it can't be treated as a `B` anymore. So it is either `C` shouldn't be a `B` to begin with or the return type of `props` needs to be something like `Any`. Would be nice explain what you actually want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need `var props` from `struct Yo` to **conform** to **two protocols**.

You can simply do this with:

```
public protocol A {}
public protocol A2 {}

struct D :  A,A2 {
}

struct Yo {
    var props: D
}
```

I don't see why would you need protocol C and B, as they add constraints to struct Yo and not to var props